Trying to find coefficient of $x^{15}$ for binomial expansion.

but $r \neq 76$ because $n = 30$. Where did I go wrong?

Please use MathJax.  Are you trying to find the coefficient of $x^{15}$ in $(x+2)(x^3+7x^2)^{30}$?

@RaulAlmuzara Lowest exponent $~x^{60}.$

@RaulAlmuzara No, the lowest exponent of $~(x+2)(x^3 + 7x^2)^{30}~$is $~x^{60},~$ which is created as the term given by $~2 \times (7x^2)^{30}.$

@user2661923 Sorry, you are right. In OP's question, the full term with lowest exponent is $2\cdot 7^{30} x^{60}$ and the full term with highest exponent is $x^{91}$.

Okay, I understand. I just came up with this problem on random without thinking too much about lowest power on x.
